# Running total in C

Tags: c

I'm new to StackOverflow and I had a simple question.

I'm writing a program that accepts strings and numbers. 
I used `fgets` to take care of the strings part.

Summary(view previous edits if you want more gist of the problem):

As per Simone's suggestion, here is what I have so far:

```
int value = -1;
int check = sscanf(command, "%i%c", &value, dummy);
if (check == 1) {
    sscanf(command, "%d" , &command_value);
    sum = sum + command_value;
    printf("Sum is now %d\n", sum);
}
else if (check == 2) {
    printf("Command unrecognized.\n");
}
```

The problem now is that It does print out the sum but with it also prints out "command unrecognized". I think I messed up the syntax again.

Comment: Is it related to homework ? If it is, then please add homework tag.

Comment: Looking at your code I can only assume you somewhere have `#define 2 1`. Of course even that wouldn't work because there's no fall through in else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit in your (edited) question is kind of important:

"I'm not sure how I can tell it so when the user enters some numbers (eg, 12), it puts it in the running total. And if the user inputs "12e" or something, that input would be ignored."

An alternative to sscanf would be to use strtol() to check whether input ends after the numeric...

```
char *end;
static int running_total = 0;  // static if you want a running total over repeated calls of this function...

[...]

command_value = strtol(command, end, 0);
if (end && (end != command) && *end == '\n')
    running_total += command_value;
```

Comment: Not sure I can use that since we have only learned some basic functions in C. I'm pretty sure I have to stick with sscanf :(

Comment: Then just check the return val for sscanf to make sure you've read one value.  What do you mean by "ignores string input"?  you already have string input in command.

Comment: I mean if I enter "14e", it would give out "command not found".

Comment: I can't comment on the original post or Simone's answer as don't have the rep, but just want to add that you should just do "else" rather than "else if (check == 2)".  Otherwise you won't go there if the text doesn't contain a number at all, eg. "help".

Comment: You don't show the rest of the code, but I would imagine that after this bit, you then enter a block where you say "if (strcmp(command, "help")) {..} else { printf("command not recognised\n"). }  You are probably doing this bit even if a number is parsed.  You should put the whole block inside the "else" of "if (check == 1)".

Comment: I thought so too. I changed it to else.

Comment: I used the strcasecmp since I wanted case insensitivity. Oh and also, I'm still having problems. Even when it adds up the sum and shows the result, it keeps saying "command unrecognized" for some reason.

Comment: gillez, if I could vote up your answer I would. The program works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Where do you do the strcasecmp?  I am sure you must be doing this after the code listed above.  Which means you are still doing it even if you enter the (check == 1) part.  You probably have another "command unrecognized" line in the else of that strcasecmp, which is the line that's causing the printout, not the line in the posted code.

Comment: Why can't you vote up my answer?  I could do with the rep so that I can comment on other original posts! :)

Comment: I meant I don't have the rep to vote up posts. This is my first post on here. But thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `sscanf()`, it should do the trick.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/.

**EDIT**
Since an input value such as "12e" would have `sscanf()` return 12, you could try something like this:

```
char dummy[1];
int value = -1;
int retv = sscanf(input_string, "%i%c", &value, dummy);
if (retv == 1) {
    // input_string is a number
}
else if (retv == 2) {
    // input_string is a number followed by some gibberish
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I tried using sscanf but when I do, it only accepts the numerical input and ignores the string inputs for some reason.

Comment: It's very close to working but when I add a number, it does sum up the number but then it also puts out command not recognized. I have edited my post above to show what I have so far.

Comment: @Watabout it seems impossible to me. Why don't you paste your code in some site like this: http://codepad.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the running total -

```
int runningTotal = 0;

.............
// Your number input arrived

runningTotal = runningTotal + your_number_input
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I know how to add. I just want to know how I can distinguish numerical inputs from the strings.

Comment: then take a look at Simone's answer.